# How to shrinkwrap devDependencies, but not install them unless necessary?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a bunch of `devDependencies` needed in order to run test suite and have production dependencies locked down with `npm shrinkwrap`. The problem is that when I run `npm install`, only production dependencies are installed, in order to install `devDependencies`, I have to remove npm-shrinkwrap.json and run it again.

Now if shrinkwrap contains `devDependencies` as well, they get installed in production, where they are not required. Surely there should be some command line arguments to force only normal dependencies to be installed?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**September, 2016:**

As others have mentioned as well, there were some huge efforts to enhance the shrinkwrap feature starting with [npm v3.10.8](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.10.8).

Thanks to [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/10073), it'll be possible to keep your `devDependencies` locked while installing only the production dependencies:

```
npm shrinkwrap --dev
npm install --only=prod
```

---

**2013 answer:**

As stated in the [NPM docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap#other-notes):

> Since `npm shrinkwrap` is intended to lock down your dependencies for
>   production use, `devDependencies` will not be included unless you
>   explicitly set the `--dev` flag when you run npm shrinkwrap. If
>   installed `devDependencies` are excluded, then npm will print a warning.
>   If you want them to be installed with your module by default, please
>   consider adding them to dependencies instead.

Basically, or you lock down all deps, or only the production deps.

Not even running `npm install --dev` or `npm install --force` can transcend the shrinkwrap functionality.

Comment: So basically there is no way to do what I'm after?

Comment: Thru the CLI, it's what it seems. You could write some code, maybe an postinstall NPM script, which install your dev dependencies if an argv `--dev` is passed, for example.

Comment: This could be coming soon, see this pull request: https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/10073

Comment: The problem is I'm not just using a shrinkwrap for my production app; I'm also using to lock down my dev dependencies so that nothing goes awry in my CI tests.

Comment: @mikestaub it's patched in 3.10.8: https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.10.8

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this feature was recently added in v3.3 of the npm client per the [changelog](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#only-also-dev)

You'll now be able to run `npm install --only=prod` to achieve the effect you wish.

Comment: Not true. This is the same as `npm install --production` with the same problems of being overriden by `npm-shrinkwrap.json`.

Comment: `npm shrinkwrap --also=dev` for the lazy. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT*** 2016/09/13

I've tested out npm v3.10.8, and this functionality now works as expected. We've shrinkwrapped our devDependencies and can install only prod dependencies when we deploy.

---

I think it's worth mentioning that this feature should start working as expected very soon. According to this github [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5403), tons of people were running into the same problem, and according to this [pull request](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/10073), it will be in the next release (scheduled for 2016-09-08).

With the pull request merged in, all you would have to do is:

```
npm i --only=prod
```

Answer (score 1):

As to npm 5 (I've tried on 5.5.1 and 5.6.0), **--production** (**--only=prod**) flag is problematic.

When *package-lock.json* exists in the folder,

```
npm shrinkwrap --production
```

simply changes the file name to *npm-shrinkwrap.json*.

How I managed to solve this issue is to run:

```
npm prune --production
```

and then run:

```
npm shrinkwrap --production
```

Comment: This was good work around, but it seems to have stopped working somewhere in the 5.x.x major of npm. See https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/166 for details on the change.  If devDeps aren't typically installed for -g installs, then they also shouldn't be installed just because there is a lock file.  This smells of incorrect behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in `npm` `3.10.8`; `npm install --production` shouldn't install dev deps in a shrinkwrap created by `npm shrinkwrap --dev`: https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.10.8