# Force npm to install the same dependencies on mutiple machines

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I have a `packages.json` file and I'm installing the needed node modules with `npm install` from the same directory where the file is located.
The problem is that I'm doing this on different machines and some of them might already have some dependencies installed globally.

This normally shouldn't represent a problem but in my case it is.
For example I need to install `grunt-contrib-uglify` and since some machine might already have some dependencies installed they won't try to fetch and get them. This lead to two slightly different versions of the dependencies tree.

**Example:**

`npm list` (truncated) produces:

```
# Machine 1

├─┬ grunt-contrib-uglify@0.2.7
│ ├─┬ grunt-lib-contrib@0.6.1
│ │ └── zlib-browserify@0.0.1
│ └─┬ uglify-js@2.4.21
│   ├── async@0.2.10
│   ├─┬ source-map@0.1.34
│   │ └── amdefine@0.1.0
│   ├── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
│   └─┬ yargs@3.5.4
│     ├── camelcase@1.0.2
│     ├── decamelize@1.0.0
│     ├── window-size@0.1.0
│     └── wordwrap@0.0.2    

# Machine2

├─┬ grunt-contrib-uglify@0.2.7
│ ├─┬ grunt-lib-contrib@0.6.1
│ │ └── zlib-browserify@0.0.1
│ └─┬ uglify-js@2.4.23
│   ├── async@0.2.10
│   ├─┬ source-map@0.1.34
│   │ └── amdefine@0.1.0
│   ├── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
│   └─┬ yargs@3.5.4
│     ├── camelcase@1.1.0
│     ├── decamelize@1.0.0
│     ├── window-size@0.1.0
│     └── wordwrap@0.0.2
```

In this case `camelcase` and `uglify-js` are not exactly the same version.
When I use this in conjunction with grunt to minify the production js files I get minor differences between the compiled files. Of course the two files acts exactly the same but for git they are different (and I would like to avoid this)

**Question**: how can I tell `npm` that I want exactly the same modules but **also** exactly the same dependencies?

Comment: Very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544051/how-to-shrinkwrap-devdependencies-but-not-install-them-unless-necessary) I just didn't know that this is called shrinkwrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution: [npm-shrinkwrap](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/02/27/managing-node-js-dependencies-with-shrinkwrap/)

So, first I should install and test the modules as normally I would with `npm install` then run `npm shrinkwrap` to lock down all the installed modules and their deps into a file called `npm-shrinkwrap.json`. We could use the flag `--dev` if we want also to save dev deps.

Then we could for example track this file with git and from other machines retrieve the tracked file.

Then normally `npm install` => If the file `npm-shrinkwrap.json` is present it will take precedence over `packages.json` and npm will use it to install exactly all the deps specified in the file.

Answer (score 2):

There is a file named [package-lock.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-lock-json). It contains the exact dependency tree of all installed packages including the registry where they were downloaded from. Whenever you add a new dependency using `npm install <package-name>` this file is updated automatically. It should be checked in into your version control.

To make sure that the same package versions listed in the file are installed in your `node_modules` folder you have to execute the command `npm ci` (ci = clean install). This is going to delete your `node_modules` folder and download the exact packages listed int the `package-lock.json`. This command should be used instead of `npm install` in any build script.

Comment: Thanks, in modern days this is true but at the time I had asked this question `package-lock.js` didn't exist :]  
Back then the only solution was `npm-shrinkwrap` which I guess is now integrated into npm itself with `package-lock.json`