# npm install has dozens of versions of same package in node_modules/.staging

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm developing a Webpack, TypeScript and Angular 1.5.x web application that uses NPM for dependency management. The application has about 3 dozen dependencies and a similar number of devDependencies listed in package.json. Many of the dependencies are internally-developed NPM packages hosted on Artifactory.

Our `npm install` is *very* slow on Jenkins (on the order of 1 hour sometimes). I've noticed the following:

During `npm install` a `.staging` directory is created under `node_modules`. Here, there are about a dozen different versions of the same dependency listed. I am assuming each of our dependencies is specifying slightly different versions of those dependencies and NPM downloads all of them to resolve them. For example

```
$ ls -al node_modules/.staging/webpack-*

webpack-02c2cd2d/ webpack-core-0e45f015/ webpack-dev-middleware-1b9e08da/     
# ...many more versions of webpack, wepack-core, webpack-dev-middleware
```

The `.staging` directory itself contains *thousands* of directories:

```
$ ls -al node_modules/.staging/ | wc -l
19406
```

My questions are the following:

1. What is the `.staging` directory for? What is npm doing with it? This question was [asked as an issue on Github](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12540) but never properly answered.
2. Why is `npm install` so slow? Why does it download so many different versions of each dependency?
3. What can I do about the slowness and apparent duplicate downloads? (apart from the solution suggested on the Github issue i.e. increase swap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what was happening:

Our internal packages were shrinkwrapped. The `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file for each package had been generated with the `--dev` flag. This means development dependencies are also shrinkwrapped.

There are two possible solutions for this:

1. Don't generate shrinkwrap JSON with the --dev flag
2. Run `npm install --only=prod`. This is supposed to skip installing devDependencies, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544051/how-to-shrinkwrap-devdependencies-but-not-install-them-unless-necessary)